# How can we integrate LinkedIn OAuth 2 Authentication php

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

How can we integrate LinkedIn Auth2 Authentication php. Currently I'm using OAuth 1.0a authentication.

if there is any php class is available please let me know

Answer (score 3):

you can use this example. by this example you can grab the whole profile from user profile.
http://pastebin.com/c7XPgZPs

```
// Change these
define('API_KEY',      'YOUR_API_KEY_HERE'                                          );
define('API_SECRET',   'YOUR_API_SECRET_HERE'                                       );
define('REDIRECT_URI', 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
define('SCOPE',        'r_fullprofile r_emailaddress rw_nus'                        );

// Congratulations! You have a valid token. Now fetch your profile 
$user = fetch('GET', '/v1/people/~:(first-name,last-name,headline,picture-url,email-address);
print "Hello $user->firstName $user->lastName.";

exit;


//get the auth url for linkedin
function getAuthorizationCode() {
    $params = array('response_type' => 'code',
                                    'client_id' => API_KEY,
                                    'scope' => SCOPE,
                                    'state' => uniqid('', true), // unique long string
                                    'redirect_uri' => REDIRECT_URI,
                      );

    // Authentication request
    $url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?' . http_build_query($params);

    // Needed to identify request when it returns to us
    $_SESSION['state'] = $params['state'];

    // Redirect user to authenticate
    header("Location: $url");
    exit;
}

function getAccessToken() {
$params = array('grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
                'client_id' => API_KEY,
                'client_secret' => API_SECRET,
                'code' => $_GET['code'],
                'redirect_uri' => REDIRECT_URI,
          );

// Access Token request
$url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken?' . http_build_query($params);

// Tell streams to make a POST request
$context = stream_context_create(
                array('http' => 
                    array('method' => 'POST',
                    )
                )
            );

// Retrieve access token information
$response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

// Native PHP object, please
$token = json_decode($response);

// Store access token and expiration time
$_SESSION['access_token'] = $token->access_token; // guard this! 
$_SESSION['expires_in']   = $token->expires_in; // relative time (in seconds)
$_SESSION['expires_at']   = time() + $_SESSION['expires_in']; // absolute time

return true;
}

function fetch($method, $resource, $body = '') {
$params = array('oauth2_access_token' => $_SESSION['access_token'],
                'format' => 'json',
          );

// Need to use HTTPS
$url = 'https://api.linkedin.com' . $resource . '?' . http_build_query($params);
// Tell streams to make a (GET, POST, PUT, or DELETE) request
$context = stream_context_create(
                array('http' => 
                    array('method' => $method,
                    )
                )
            );


// Hocus Pocus
$response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

// Native PHP object, please
return json_decode($response);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks kleopatra, please guide me for creating logout process and CSRF token generation.